# What mistake am I making when trying to apply Fermat's little theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, congruences

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications 
[image]

This is Fermat's little theorem from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0ZQvZLx2KA,
[image]

Here is my work so far

First 41 is prime and $41\not\mid23$

So $23^{40}\equiv1\pmod {41}$

From my observation that $1002/40 = 25$, I rooted both sides of $23^{40}\equiv1$ by $25$

(allowed to so by Congruence product rule, [Divisibility for 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879251/divisibility-for-7/879262#879262))
Here is what am I left with 
$$23^{1000}\equiv1\pmod {41}$$
Then I used the fact that $1002 \mod 40 = 2$ and the congruence product rule to get 
$$23^{1002}\equiv 23^2\pmod {41}$$
Then with this property from my book
[image]

I know that $23^{1002}\mod 41 =  23^2 \mod 41$. 
$23^2\mod 41$ from my calculator is $18$ so that be my final answer as well. 
But when I checked my answer on http://www.mathcelebrity.com/modexp.php?num=+23%5E1002+mod+41&pl=Modular+Exponentiation, the correct answer was 37.

Does anyone know I did wrong -either arithmetically or applying theorems?

Comment: Your calculator misled you when you found $23^2(\mod41)$

Comment: Actually I think I mislead myself haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 41\!:\,\  23^2 \equiv (-2\cdot9)^2 \equiv\, 4(\overbrace{-1}^{\large81}) \equiv 37.\ $ Trust your brain more than your calculator.

Comment: How did you get 23$^2$≡(−2⋅9)$^2$?

Comment: @com ${\rm mod}\ 41\!:\ 23\equiv 23-41\equiv -18.\ $ Generally modular arithmetic is easier with least magnitude reps, here $\,|{-}18| < 23.\ $ Recall also the use of $\,-1\,$ vs. $\,m\!-\!1\pmod m\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$$23^2 \equiv (20+3)^2=20*20+20*2*3+9=\\
= 40*10+40*3+9 \equiv -10-3+9=-4=37 \pmod{41}$$